# STArtThread

Tags: .net, c, wpf

HI All i'm completing a sample Project(WPF) to show my boss but i need a feature to finish it.
I have a Login Window to authenticate and access in the software now i wish put this LoginWindow as  STArtThread so if the user can authenticate(with right password and username) automatically the LoginWindow disappear and can access to use the software.
Do you have any idea how work out this feature?
Thanks for your attention.
Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do background work in either Windows Forms or WPF is to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

There are various examples and blog posts using BackgroundWorker with WPF. Rather than list them here, I'll just say that a search for WPF and BackgroundWorker gives good results :)

Alternatively, you should look into the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) which is at the heart of the WPF threading model. The [MSDN article about WPF threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) is probably the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work the same in a WPF application, but in WinForms I would show the login form as a dialog first, and then just... not start the main form if the login failed. Maybe something similar is possible with WPF?